# clang: error: unknown argument: '-no_adhoc_codesign'

Tags: c++, macos, linker, dylib

I'm trying to get rid of **linker-signed** out of my xxx.dylib. So according to [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/697361), I added `-no_adhoc_codesign` to linker flag with `-DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-no_adhoc_codesign"` but it seems clang has no idea about this flag. ld does have [this option](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/ld.1.html)

`clang: error: unknown argument: '-no_adhoc_codesign'`

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ --version
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.3)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: How exactly are you invoking clang? Can you show the actual command.

Comment: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -fuse-ld=ld -stdlib=libc++ .... -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -no_adhoc_codesign -o output/xxx.dylib`  It's from Clion run

Comment: try `-Wl,-no_adhoc_codesign` to pass the option directly to the linker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-Wl,-no_adhoc_codesign` to pass the option directly to the linker if the compiler doesn't support adding the option itself.